# How to remove /* sonam */ in xslt string

Tags: xslt-1.0

In XSLT my string is this

```
create or replace trigger "NEW"./*$Revision: $ */
reservation_receipts_jrnl.
```

I want to remove `/*$Revision: $ */` from my sting.

How can I do it?

Comment: That's not XSLT code, and I have no idea what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string is actually a text node somewhere in your input XML document, you can use the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions to extract the wanted parts.

If the string can contain more than one of these comments, you will need to use a recursive named template to replace all such occurrences with nothing.